# Оптимизация кода и избавление от InvokeRepeating Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код который по команде постепенно меняет прозрачность(просто альфа компонент)

Вызываем

```
InvokeRepeating("MoreTransparency", 0, 0.1f);
InvokeRepeating("LessTransparency", 0, 0.1f);
```

Выполняем

```
private void LessTransparency()
{
    if (alphalvl >= 1)
    {
    CancelInvoke("LessTransparency");
    }
    CancelInvoke("MoreTransparency");
    alphalvl = alphalvl + 0.3f;
    ChangeColor();
}
private void MoreTransparency()
{
    if(alphalvl <= 0)
    {
        CancelInvoke("MoreTransparency");
    }
    CancelInvoke("LessTransparency");
    alphalvl = alphalvl - 0.3f;
    ChangeColor();
```

Код выглядит громоздко и вообще так себе. Но работает.
Как подобное можно переделать в один красивый метод?

Comment: А что за `ChangeColor()` ? Откуда вызываются InvokeRepeating("MoreTransparency" и InvokeRepeating("LessTransparency" ?  Прозрачность меняется как мигание или одноразово с одного значения до другого (например нажали одну кнопку - уменьшилась прозрачность, нажали другую - увеличилась)?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нажали - запустился InvokeRepeating, объект  постепенно стал из прозрачного - непрозрачным. 
Нажали другую кнопку - объект медленно растворился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильней будет так:

```
 private void LessTransparency()
    {
        alphalvl +=  0.3f;
        if (alphalvl >= 1)
        {
        alphalvl  = 1;
        CancelInvoke("LessTransparency");
        }
       // CancelInvoke("MoreTransparency"); <--- зачем?  

        ChangeColor();
    }
```

Можно так еще попробовать:

```
   void Start ()
    {      
        StartCoroutine("MoreTransparency");
    }


    IEnumerator MoreTransparency()
    {                  
        while(alphalvl  <= 1)
        {
            ChangeColor();                
            alphalvl  += 0.1f;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }             
    }
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Или универсальная функция:

```
void Start ()
{      
    StartCoroutine("ChangeTransparency", -0.1);
}

IEnumerator ChangeTransparency(float val)
{   
    // Чтобы избежать бесконечного цикла.        
    if (val != 0)
       while(val > 0 ? alphalvl <= 1 : alphalvl >= 0)
       {
           ChangeColor();  
           alphalvl += val;
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
       }             
}
```

Comment: Дак это всё равно два метода. Да еще и корутина. Это усложнение кода имхо. А нужно либо уменьшение в размере, либо упрошение. 
`CancelInvoke("MoreTransparency");`
преследует простую цель - если мы нажмем кнопку *убрать прозрачность* во время работы кнопки *добавить прозрачность*, они будут мешать друг другу. `CancelInvoke("MoreTransparency");` обрывает конкурирующий процесс при запуске нового.

PS Увидел новый вариант с универсальной функцией. Опробую, отпишусь о результатах

Comment: Усложнение кода - это когда метод увеличения прозрачности, почему отвечает и за метод уменьшения.

Comment: Не могли бы вы расписать, что дает вот этот участок кода
`while(val > 0 ? alphalvl <= 1 : alphalvl >= 0)`
Я так понял, этот аналог кода 
`while(if (val >0){alphalvl <= 1}else{alphalvl >=0)`

И мне совершенно непонятно как оно работает. Объясните пожалуйста текстом или более простым кодом, без тернарного оператора

Comment: @Dmitrii, Ты правильно понял. Работает так: если val < 0, то прозрачность идет на убывание. И нужно проверять что бы она не стала ниже нуля.  Если val > 0, то прозрачность идет на повышение, то она не должна превысить единицу.